# Yii2 params access within local config file in common directory

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using `Yii2` advanced template,
I want to access `params.php` in `main-local.php` file,
I called this ways:

**main-local.php:**

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'myClass',
             'apikey' => \Yii::$app->params['mandrill_api_key'],
             'viewPath' => '@common/mail',            
        ],
```

and I have stored this `mandrill_api_key` in `params.php`

**params.php:**

```
<?php
return [
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',
    'supportEmail' => 'support@example.com',
    'user.passwordResetTokenExpire' => 3600,
     'mandrill_api_key' => 'mykey'
];
```

I'm getting this error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\common\config\main-local.php on line 25

What should I do to access these parameters?

Comment: did you try adding a \, so something like: \Yii::$app->params['mandrill_api_key']

Comment: Yes I have tried this but not working, may be I need to define something when application bootstraping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config files are read before the application is instantiated as explained in the [request lifecycle](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-workflow.html#request-lifecycle):

> 1. A user makes a request to the entry script web/index.php.
> 2. The entry script loads the application configuration and creates an application instance to handle the request.
> 3. The application resolves the requested route with the help of the request application component.
> 4. ...

As such `\Yii::$app` does not yet exist hence the error. I would suggest moving your api_key definition to the `main-local.php` config such that there is no confusion over where it is being set:

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'myClass',
    'apikey' => 'actual api key',
    'viewPath' => '@common/mail',            
],
```

Alternatively, you can use Yii2's [dependancy injection container](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html) to set the `apikey` in your application's entry script:

```
...
$app = new yii\web\Application($config);
\Yii::$container->set('\fully\qualified\myClass', [
    'apikey' => \Yii::$app->params['mandrill_api_key'],
]);
$app->run();
```

Comment: Thanks  I will try, but my issue is, I have to get this API key from database and set in config.

Comment: as @huss pointed you could directly use $params in local config files

Answer (score 3):

You can just do

```
$params['mandrill_api_key']
```

you dont need to use

```
\Yii::$app->params['mandrill_api_key']
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Yii2 config loads the params file at starting main-config script

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

So you can use $params array in any part of your file

Answer (score 1):

The params is a part of config and you can not call this in your config .

the best way for handel this you can use this in your class :

myClass:

```
class myClass extends ... {

    public $apikey;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->apikey =  \Yii::$app->params['mandrill_api_key'];
    }


}
```