# Use Class Object In Params - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm using `Yii2-basic-app` for now. I'm facing difficultly in calling class object in **params.php**.

I wanted to assign few params variable through database table's. And, I called using

**params.php**

```
$modelQueue =  new \app\modules\queue\models\Queues();

$params = [
  .
  .
  .
];
```

But, **error** coming

> **Fatal error**: Class 'app\modules\queue\models\Queues' not found in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyProject/config/params.php on line 13

**Directory Structure**

```
-assets
-commands
-components
-config
  -db.php
  -params.php
-controllers
-models
-modules
  -queue
    -controllers
    -models
      -Queues.php
    -views
    Queue.php
-runtime
```

I'm not getting how to call that class object. Because with help of this only I will set some data to params variable.
Any help/hint/suggestions is appreciable.

Comment: Looks like the class you are calling there is not loaded yet. Is it necessary to set params at this stage?

Comment: Yes. That is the problem. *~..class you are calling there is not loaded yet*.. Yes @Bizley. Need those table values here.

Comment: If you provide the purpose of `$modelQueue` in `params.php` maybe we can find the way around this problem.

Comment: See, cron settings I wanted to use in this params.php from where I wanted to use it in code. @Bizley

Comment: You can always prepare method in `Queues()` that will return the value when it's needed so instead of calling `Yii::$app->params['some_parameter']` you can call `(new Queues())->preparedMethod()` or  `Queues::preparedMethod()` in case of static one.

Comment: I have same problem in yii2 advance app, some one suggest me Yii2's dependancy injection container, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689230/yii2-params-access-within-local-config-file-in-common-directory

Comment: Useful Post @Shahzad *Bhai*. Happy Independence Day `:D` Shukriya