# Yii2 Set component value dynamically

Tags: php, yii2

I am using this library https://github.com/yiioverflow/yii2-imap

```
 'imap' => [
                'class' => 'roopz\imap\Imap',
                'connection' => [
                    'imapPath' => '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX',
                    'imapLogin' => 'abc@gmail.com',//set this value dynamically
                    'imapPassword' => '123',//set this value dynamically
                    'serverEncoding' => 'encoding', // utf-8 default.
                    'attachmentsDir' => 'uploads/attachments'
                ],
            ],
  //Create imap class object
  $mailbox = yii::$app->imap->connection;
  // Read all messaged into an array:
  $mailsIds = $mailbox->searchMailbox('ALL');
```

in controller. want to set this value with help of session in yii2.

Comment: Would you please explain in brief

Comment: You need to Yii2's dependancy injection container, please check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689230/yii2-params-access-within-local-config-file-in-common-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found alternative php-imap library  here [PHP IMAP][1]

[1]: https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap. which can be easily install with composer in yii2. and can pass a dynamic value

```
  $mailbox = new PhpImap\Mailbox('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'some@gmail.com', '*********', __DIR__);
  // Read all messaged into an array:
  $mailsIds = $mailbox->searchMailbox('ALL');
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing dynamic values that depends on `Yii::$app` right in config will not work because you are referring to application, and it's constructed using that config (components is a part of application too) and doesn't exist at this moment. It needs to be set later, when application is initialized and `Yii::$app` object exists. For example, in controller or some custom component.

Using library [yiioverflow/yii2-imap](https://github.com/yiioverflow/yii2-imap) it can be done like this:

```
use Yii;

...

Yii:$app->imap->connection = [
    'imapPath' => '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX',
    'imapLogin' => $imapLogin, // Set this value dynamically
    'imapPassword' => $imapPassword, // Set this value dynamically
    'serverEncoding' => 'encoding', // utf-8 default
    'attachmentsDir' => 'uploads/attachments',
],
```

Then you need to call:

```
Yii:$app->imap->createConnection();
```

to properly update the config.

There is no way to set separately `imapLogin` or `imapPassword` because of the way this component is written (these properties are protected and filled from `connection` array). If you want to do that, you have to subclass this component and write these setters by yourself and replace used component with your custom one.

More info about application components can be found in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-application-components.html).

Comment: get this error PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Cannot use object of type roopz\imap\Imap as array

Comment: @SantoshRamKunjir It's not clear what type `connection` property has from your question. I updated the answer, hope you get the idea.

Comment: @SantoshRamKunjir It's better to mention such details initially. I updated the answer according to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use own "service layer" (that works similar to global `Yii::$app`). Just create `\yii\di\ServiceLocator` instance:

```
// Init service layer.
$services = new ServiceLocator();
$services->setComponents([
    'imap' => [
        'class' => 'roopz\imap\Imap',
        'connection' => [
            'imapPath' => '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX',
            'imapLogin' => 'abc@gmail.com',//set this value dynamically
            'imapPassword' => '123',//set this value dynamically
            'serverEncoding' => 'encoding', // utf-8 default.
            'attachmentsDir' => 'uploads/attachments'
        ],
    ],
    // ...
]);


// Retrieving the defined components:
$imap = $services->get('imap');
$imap = $services->imap;
```

If `imap` component will use only your controller, you can store `$services` as protected/private property of this controller.
Described approach works completely similarly to usual components in `Yii::$app`, because application class is also ServiceLocator.

Alternatively, you can define or redefine your component using imap-instance:

```
// Preparing components
$defaultImapConfig = [
    'connection' => [
        'imapPath'       => '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX',
        'imapLogin'      => null,
        'imapPassword'   => null,
        'serverEncoding' => 'encoding', // utf-8 default.
        'attachmentsDir' => 'uploads/attachments'
    ],
];


// Init service layer.
$services = new ServiceLocator();


// Define component 
$imap = new \roopz\imap\Imap(ArrayHelper::merge($defaultImapConfig, ['connection' => [
    'imapLogin'     => 'abc@gmail.com',
    'imapPassword'  => '123',
]]));

$services->set('imap', $imap);


// Redefine component with new config
$imap = new \roopz\imap\Imap(ArrayHelper::merge($defaultImapConfig, ['connection' => [
    'imapLogin'     => 'dfg@gmail.com',
    'imapPassword'  => '456',
]]));

$services->set('imap', $imap);      // If component definition with the same name already exist, it will be ovewritten.
```

Of course, you can use similar way to redefine global components in `Yii::$app`, but it is bad practice. I recommend to create separate (local) service layer, that can be accessed from your controllers, models etc.

More details about work with service locators you can found [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-service-locator.html).